# How to get spring cache size in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I have two methods as follows:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "foos")
  public List<FooDto> getAllFoos() {
    return this.fooRepository.findAll().stream()
      .map(FooEntityDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto) // mapping entity to dto
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "foos",key = "#fooDto.Id")
  public FooDto getFooById(FooDto fooDto) {
    return this.fooRepository.findById(fooDto.getId()).stream()
      .map(FooEntityDomainToDtoMapper::mapDomainToDto) // mapping entity to dto
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

First `getAllFoos()` will be called during the System startup and second will be called after starting the system when user request object by particular id. I wanted to know whether second method will occupy any separate cache space or it'll simply add keys in the cache obtained in the first method? I want to confirm that even if i comment the second `getFooById()` whether or not the size of the cache will be the same? Is there any way to get the size of cache?

P.S: we are not using any implementation of cache, just using `spring-boot-starter-cache`

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780249/spring-boot-cachable-cache-size ?

Comment: Yeah, thought about it @smit. But thought, maybe they have included some new stuffs in later versions

Answer (score 0):

Although, there is no direct method through which you can see cache data and get size but you can do that by using reflection. Here is what I've done.

```
public Object getAllCache() {
 //Autowire your cache manager first and then process the request using cache manager
        ConcurrentMapCache cache = (ConcurrentMapCache) manager.getCache("yourCachename");
        Object store1 = null;
        try {
            Field store = ConcurrentMapCache.class.getDeclaredField("store");
            store.setAccessible(true);
            store1 =  store.get(cache);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return store1.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope you're using Spring Cache. So it depends on which cache implementation you are using. Unfortunately Spring Cache is only an abstraction layer.

You can use the Caffeine implementation with `spring-boot-starter-cache` and set the size in `application.properties` or `application.yml` file. Then you can manage your cache size.

Example:

```
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=500
```

And add to pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```